# Do you know any jokes that aliens might enjoy?

Tags: astrobiology

What are some jokes that aliens can understand without a lot of knowledge on humans?

I think that humour is an essential part of being a human. And if we ever make contact with aliens then we should be prepare some jokes for them

Do you know any jokes that aliens might understand? I assume that it must rely on basic concepts that aliens will also have: math, physics, chemistry.

If we make some assumptions about nature of those aliens then we can use some higher-level concepts like:

- biological inheritance/ancestry
- food, excrements
- being late/disorganised

Crack your best ones for humanity's sake

Comment: Stack exchange works best when the questions that are asked have right-or-wrong type answers rather than being open-ended. This question is suitable for a discussion forum, which this isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll rephrase my question to have a clear goal. most of the questions on the 'original' stackoverflow.com are open-ended questions as there's usually more than 1 way to solve a given problem.

Comment: @IvanDenysov Astronomy SE has no problem with jokes, but [they keep them in meta](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/q/323/7982). This is a really interesting question and I have often wondered if it's time for a Humor SE site where questions can be asked about why thing are funny. I had one successful humor-based question in Movies SE: [Carson: “It was so X”; Audience: “How X was it?”](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/110906/45856) but I don't think it exploring "humor theory" is sustainable there, nor in Philosophy SE.

Comment: @IvanDenysov there is [Psychology and Neurology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions) fo some aspects of humor, but wow, *alien humor* is going to be tough.